# Remove a list of files over SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to do the following:

Retrieve a list of remote files matching a glob pattern:

```
existing_files=$(ssh user@example.com "ls pattern*")
```

Add a new file that matches the pattern:

```
scp pattern_matching_file user@example.com:
```

Now I'd like to delete the files in `$existing_file` without deleting the newly created file, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: The best solution I've come up with is: `echo "$existing_files" | ssh user@example.com 'while read f; do rm "$f"; done'` which works, but I wonder if there's a way to do this with a single rm command.

Comment: Why don't you just `rm` the files instead of listing them?

Comment: Clarification: I delete the existing files only after the scp (in actuality, it's piping zfs send directly to the ssh host, something like `zfs send ... | ssh user@example.com 'cat - > file'`) exits with status 0. It's for backups, so I only want to delete old files after a new copy is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got

> ```
> scp pattern_matching_file user@example.com:
> ```

and you then want to delete all the files in that directory *except* for the one you've just transferred. Here are two suggestions:

1. Delete all the files before the copy

   ```
   ssh -qn user@example.com 'find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*pattern*' -delete'
   ```
2. Delete the files except the one you've just copied

   ```
   ssh -qn user@example.com 'find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name 'keep_this_file' -o -name '*pattern*' -delete \)'
   ```

In both cases, depending on the actual target path you may feel happy omitting `-name '*pattern*'` to delete everything (including dot files, mind) in the named directory. The `find` command takes a simplified shell glob for the `-name` pattern so it should be find to use the original `pattern` you supplied for `ls`.

**Replace `-delete` with `-print` to test any theory before applying it.**

---

If you want to retrieve a list of files matching a pattern, you could use `ls {pattern}` but that would also descend into any directories that matched. The `-d` flag would avoid that, but you'd still end up with complications should any filename contain a newline character `\n`. Particularly if you're going to use that list for deleting files later.

As an alternative you could build an array of files like this

```
files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    files+=("$file")
done < <( ssh -qn user@example.com find -maxdepth 1 -name '*pattern*' -print0 )

# Show what we caught
for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo ">$file<"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! Suggestion 2 works great for my needs. At first glance I would read that command as using -delete on either `keep_this_file` OR `*pattern*`. I'm unfamiliar with the logical operators in `find`. In actuality I guess the presumed AND between `-name '*pattern*'` and `-delete` means only the files matching that pattern are deleted, yet I'm unsure how the first `-name 'keep_this_file'` is excluded.

Comment: Okay... I think I get it. When going through files, if `-name 'keep_this_file'` is not matched, then `-name '*pattern*'` is searched thanks to the logical OR. If that matches, the accompanying `-delete` is performed. When `-name 'keep_this_file'` is matched, nothing happens due to the absence of `-delete` or `-print`. Another working solution is: `ssh -qn user@example.com 'find -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -not -name 'keep_this_file' -name '*pattern*' -delete \)'`